# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
> implements Countable
>
> Filename: helpers/get_option_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 9

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('get_option')) {

    function get_option( $option_name, $default = false ) {
          $CI =& get_instance();
          $settings = $CI->db->get_where("opts", array("option_name" => $option_name));

          if(count($settings->row())) return $settings->row('option_value'); 

          return $default;
    }

}

?>
```

How to solve this problem

Comment: Well, `$settings->row()` is clearly not countable. Have you tried dumping its value to see what you got?

Answer (score -1):

All right, after some homework, I believe that you're asking the question in the wrong place!

Googling for this error, which seems to be a [popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612772/there-is-an-error-in-my-code-but-i-couldnt-solve-it), and seeing a large number of websites that currently throw this error, I assume the following:

1. You're running an auction website (most likely for domain auctions, but possibly other kinds of auctions).
2. You're using crivion's [PHP Auctions Script](https://codecanyon.net/item/php-auctions-script/19510514). Almost everybody having this error on that file & line number are using an old version of that script.
3. You've recently upgraded to a more recent version of PHP (possibly going from 7.3 to 7.4 or even 8). It's even likely that such an upgrade was done directly by the hosting company you're using for your website, and there is no way to go back to an older version (mostly for security reasons).
4. You have little or no knowledge of PHP (fixing the above code is *trivial*).

You basically have two options:

1. If you're *a legitimate owner* of a license to crivion's PHP Auctions Script, you can ask for help [on the Envato/CodeCanyon webpage for that script](https://codecanyon.net/item/php-auctions-script/19510514). That license should, additionally, give you access to:

   1. a (free) download of the latest version of PHP Auctions Script (1.4 as I write these lines), which should work with PHP 7.4 or even 8;
   2. customer support directly from crivion, if your license has been renewed in the past 12 months *or*
   3. access to the discussion page, which ought to be free to access for registered users, and crivion usually answers there frequently.
2. But since *legitimate* customers of crivion's PHP Auctions Script already know all the above, it's also possible that you have gotten that script from NullJungle — which has a *pirated* copy of version 1.3 as a 'free download', which, of course, won't get him any money whatsoever to be able to support you with your enquiries.
3. It's also possible that you got the PHP Auctions Script from any other sources, unaware that this is a *paid* product and requiring a valid license to operate. It's not uncommon to pay a so-called 'website designer' to create a specific website, and what *they* do is simply grab a script out of the Internet, and charge *you* for the finished product (the complete website). In that case, it's *that* 'website designer' that is responsible to fix your issues — and even if they don't know how to fix it, they *should* have a valid license from crivion and get support from him. If not... well, that would mean that you have been tricked by this 'website designer', who sold you something that they never bought in the first place, hoping that you wouldn't figure it out...

That said, of course I'm not the 'moral police' around here; that's something between you and crivion, or between you and whatever middle-man you've hired to set up your website.

Fixing this specific error is really quite simple; all you need to do is to *additionally* check if `$settings->row()` is countable or not; for good measure, check if `$settings` is `empty()` or not. If you're knowledgeable enough, you should accomplish that very easily; if you're a licensed customer of crivion, you can get crivion to do that for you.

Comment: Why have you posted an identical answer to two different questions, even linking between them? Content duplication is something SO wants to avoid. Writing an answer to one of the questions and simply leaving a comment under the other would have been the most sensible approach to this.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry; let me edit the other answer.

Comment: Correction, I've deleted the other answer and just added a comment to this one.

Comment: As a side note, I _did_ inform crivion of the situation as well. I have no idea how he will address it, though; he thanked me for the report.